# How to do data integrity and error handling?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, web-services

Maybe this is a silly question, but after I asked some friends and googled for a while, and still cannot find a good explanation.

For example, I will do follow operations when one user posts:

1. MySQL.insert(user, postTitle, postBody, time)
2. Redis.incr user.totalPostCount
3. Redis.set last10Posts

So my question is, for example, if `1` success but `2` fails, what should I do?

Ignore the redis error and continue? then `user.totalPostCount` is incorrect.

Retry `redis.incr`? What to do if retry fails?

Return error to end-user says `post fail` and let user post again?

Delete the post which previously inserted and return error to user?

```
mysql.insert({user: user, postTitle: postTitle, postBody: postBody}, function(err, mysqlId) {
  if(err) { return Error(500); }
  redis.incr({user: user, totalPostCount}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) { mysql.delete(mysqlId)}
    setLast10Post({newPost: {postTitle...}}, function(err, result) {
      if(err) {mysql.delete(mysqlId); redis.decr({user.totalPostcount})}
    })
  })
```

})

Comment: Why close? I think it is quite common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want those 3 operations to be a single atomic operation. That is, if any step fails, you want to make sure the whole thing fails and nothing happens.

So for scenario 1 (1 success, 2 fail), you'd rollback the SQL query and report an error. You could forget anything happened or retry the whole process at that point.

As for actually creating this transaction, perhaps this [link](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions) is helpful.

Comment: How to make it a single atomic operation? Can I make these three steps a transaction?

Comment: It's hard to prescribe a specific solution without seeing your code. Maybe you have a callback for the user action and all these actions are encapsulated in that callback. When one of them fails, in your error handler you rollback whatever else had already happened and then cancel the operation. Does that make sense? I guess strictly speaking that wouldn't be a transaction if some catastrophic thing happened in the middle of it all. You could definitely make an actual transaction out of those though.

Comment: I have add some code, so I have to check every error and rollback previous operations? so what happens if operation in rollback fails?